# Performance test sql queries

Tags: sql, oracle, performance-testing, exadata

We have two identical Oracle Exadata quarter racks each running a pair of database instances. My wet-finger-in-the-wind performance tests indicate that one is running at a quarter of the speed of the other.

Is there a set of SQL queries that can be run with timers that would give a more scientific comparison of query performance between the two servers?

I'm aware that I could write a set of queries. I'm wondering if a semi-standard benchmark set already exists. Something like a few table creation queries followed by iterative insertion statements (lots of random data), index, constraint, trigger, function, proc & view creation scripts (preferably including materialised views) and then a bunch of complex queries that stretch the engine a bit with joins, trigger firing, function and proc calls, etc... while writing performance stats to some temp tables?

Anyone come across such a library/tool/script-set?

Comment: Considering this hasn't gotten any answers yet, would you mind if I migrate it to http://dba.stackexchange.com/ for you?

Comment: There's TPC benchmarks, but I think you have to pay money to use those.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the awrgrpt.sql for each rack and compare the output. Usually it is found here ${ORACLE_HOME}/rdbms/admin/awrgrpt.sql

This will give you a bunch of information like wait events, and top sql statistics. Should give you a clue as to why one has degraded performance over the other.